# How to specify template, or tokens in filename of Enterprise Library Logging file listener

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

From what I read it appears, that enterprise library does not allow tokens in filename, which is very strange, because all other logging solutions do.

It's very confusing, I am definetly missing something. Cause I am not even able to specify Process name in flat or lolling file listener.

NLog

```
<target name="txtFile"
    xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${cached:cached=true:inner=${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss}}.txt"
    layout="${longdate} ${level} ${message}"/>
```

Log4Net

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="~/App_Data/%property{LogName}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I know (excluding programmatic setup) now is using Environment Variables on Process Level

```
<add name="loggingErrorsLog"                
     fileName="%LOGS_DIR%\%PROCESSNAME%\loggingErrors.log" ...
```

And to set those variables in code:

```
var logsDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EnvVarLogsRoot, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) ?? "Logs";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(EnvVarLogsRoot, logsDir);
```